# What is [{ }] notation in PHP

Tags: php, json, bigcommerce

Can you help me figure out this notation:

```
$myArray = jason_encode( [{ '
    'email' => 'a@bc.com', 
    'firstname' => 'peter',
    'last_name' => 'griffin',
    'company' => 'Nantuket Brewing',
    'Addresses' => [{
        'addr1' => '31 Spooner Ln',
        'city' => 'Quahog',
        'state' => 'RI'
     }]
}]
```

`jason_encode()` converts the data structure into a flat string of most key: value pairs and such.

I get that `[]` means array

Why the `[{ }]` notation?

It looks like I maybe confusing combined protocols. the original string looks like:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "[\n  {\n    \"email\": \"string@example.com\",\n    \"first_name\": \"string\",\n    \"last_name\": \"string\",\n    \"company\": \"string\",\n    \"phone\": \"string\",\n    \"notes\": \"string\",\n    \"tax_exempt_category\": \"string\",\n    \"customer_group_id\": 0,\n  \"addresses\": [\n      {\n        \"address1\": \"Addr 1\",\n        \"address2\": \"\",\n        \"address_type\": \"residential\",\n      \"city\": \"San Francisco\",\n        \"company\": \"History\",\n      \"country_code\": \"US\",\n        \"first_name\": \"Ronald\",\n       \"last_name\": \"Swimmer\",\n        \"phone\": \"707070707\",\n       \"postal_code\": \"33333\",\n        \"state_or_province\": \"California\",\n        \"form_fields\": [\n          {\n            \"name\": \"test\",\n            \"value\": \"test\"\n          }\n    ]\n      }\n    ],\n    \"authentication\": {\n      \"force_password_reset\": true,\n      \"new_password\": \"string123\"\n    },\n    \"accepts_product_review_abandoned_cart_emails\": true,\n    \"store_credit_amounts\": [\n      {\n        \"amount\": 43.15\n      }\n    ],\n    \"origin_channel_id\": 1,\n    \"channel_ids\": [\n     1\n    ],\n    \"form_fields\": [\n      {\n        \"name\": \"test\",\n        \"value\": \"test\"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n]",
```

I think what I'm seeing as PHP is actually hand json encoding.

This string works but when I try to assemble the string on my own, the API fails it with

> {"status":422,"title":"The request payload has to be a JSON array for
> the
> endpoint","type":"https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/api-status-codes","errors":{}}

This is the string I'm making:

```
{"email":"lucy@peanuts.mil","first_name":"Lucy","last_name":"van Pelt","company":"Peanuts LTD","phone":"2345551234","notes":"","tax_exempt_category":"","customer_group_id":0,"addresses":{"address1":"120 Great Pumpkin Ln","address2":"","address_type":"residential","city":"St Paul","company":"Peanuts LTD","country_code":"US","first_name":"Lucy","last_name":"van Pelt","phone":"2345551234","postal_code":"55101","state_or_province":"Minnesota","form_fields":{"name":"Are your sales tax exempt? ","value":"No"}},"authentication":{"force_password_reset":false,"New_password":"PeanutsLTD"},"accepts_product_review_abandoned_cart_emails":true,"store_credit_amounts":{"amount":12.34},"origin_channel_id":1,"channel_ids":[1],"attributes":{"name":"gp_customer_id","value":"2112"}}
```

My code:

```
$insertStr =json_encode([
            'email' => 'lucy@peanuts.mil',
            'first_name' => 'Lucy',
            'last_name' => 'van Pelt',
            'company' => 'Peanuts LTD',
            'phone' => '2345551234',
            'notes' => '',
            'tax_exempt_category' => '',
            'customer_group_id' => 0,
            'addresses' => [
                'address1' => '120 Great Pumpkin Ln',
                'address2' => '',
                'address_type' => 'residential',
                'city' => 'St Paul',
                'company' => 'Peanuts LTD',
                'country_code'  => 'US',
                'first_name'  => 'Lucy',
                'last_name'  => 'van Pelt',
                'phone' => '2345551234',
                'postal_code' => '55101',
                'state_or_province' => 'Minnesota',
                'form_fields' => [
                    'name' => 'Are your sales tax exempt? ',
                    'value' => 'No'
                ]
            ],
            'authentication' => [
                'force_password_reset' => false,
                'New_password' => 'PeanutsLTD'
            ],
            'accepts_product_review_abandoned_cart_emails' => true,
            'store_credit_amounts' => [ 'amount' => 12.34],
            'origin_channel_id' => 1,
            'channel_ids' => [1],
            'attributes' => [
                'name' => 'gp_customer_id',
                'value' => '2112'
            ]
    ]);
```

Comment: The quote on the first line looks like a typo. And `jason_encode` should be `json_encode`.

Comment: This gives me a parse error.

Comment: Right. There's an obsolete syntax using `{}` for array indexing, like `$array{1}`. But it can't be used with literals.

Comment: My apologies for the basicness and awkwardness of this question. I took 13 years off from coding to be a stay-at-home dad for the 5 children we adopted. This is my first coding position back and BC answer for everything is use the auto generated code in our API reference, it's magic. I just want to understand and I'm getting frustrated. :/

Comment: It seems like json_encode is converting all my arrays "[]" into object "{}" ... yet another issue

Comment: @Jimbus `json_encode` will decode any array with non-numeric keys into an object - how else should it be representing in json? If it's an empty array, it should still be converted to an array (since there are no non-numeric keys). So `json_encode("[]")` returns `[]` unless you did `json_encode("[]", JSON_FORCE_OBJECT )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encoding a PHP associative array. That's encoded as a JSON object.

As the error message from the API says, it's expecting an array, not an object. You need to wrap the associative array inside an ordinary array. So add another set of `[]` around it.

You have to do the same thing with the `addresses` and `attributes` arrays.

```
$insertStr =json_encode([[
            'email' => 'lucy@peanuts.mil',
            'first_name' => 'Lucy',
            'last_name' => 'van Pelt',
            'company' => 'Peanuts LTD',
            'phone' => '2345551234',
            'notes' => '',
            'tax_exempt_category' => '',
            'customer_group_id' => 0,
            'addresses' => [[
                'address1' => '120 Great Pumpkin Ln',
                'address2' => '',
                'address_type' => 'residential',
                'city' => 'St Paul',
                'company' => 'Peanuts LTD',
                'country_code'  => 'US',
                'first_name'  => 'Lucy',
                'last_name'  => 'van Pelt',
                'phone' => '2345551234',
                'postal_code' => '55101',
                'state_or_province' => 'Minnesota',
                'form_fields' => [
                    'name' => 'Are your sales tax exempt? ',
                    'value' => 'No'
                ]]
            ],
            'authentication' => [
                'force_password_reset' => false,
                'New_password' => 'PeanutsLTD'
            ],
            'accepts_product_review_abandoned_cart_emails' => true,
            'store_credit_amounts' => [ 'amount' => 12.34],
            'origin_channel_id' => 1,
            'channel_ids' => [1],
            'attributes' => [[
                'name' => 'gp_customer_id',
                'value' => '2112'
            ]]
    ]]);
```

Comment: I think I came to the same conclusion about the same time you did. I've updated with the actual code

Comment: This is now a completely different question.

Comment: It is, but really trying to learn and solve, I'm not waiting around for the answer to be posted :)

Comment: I posted the answer to the new question.

Comment: Not working, replacing each { } in the encoded string with [{ }] works... maybe their API is wonky?

Comment: You need to use the same `[[]]` for the other arrays of objects. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Basically, everywhere you see `[{}]` in the JSON, you should have `[[]]` in the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid PHP syntax.

Depending on the semantic of the data you want to encode, the outer `{` and `}` either are not needed or they must be replaced by `[` and `]`.

If the data is a list of users then it should be like this:

```php
json_encode([['email' => 'a@bc.com', ...], ['email' => 'w@xy.z', ...]]);
```

It is an array of arrays.

If the data represents a single user then it should be only `['email' => '...', ...]` (no outer `{` and `}`).

For `Addresses`, the plural tells that it is a list, so the curly braces (`{` and `}`) must be replaced by square brackets (`[` and `]`) to represent a list containing only one array.

I think it should be like this:

```php
$data = [
  [
    'email' => 'a@bc.com', 
    'firstname' => 'peter',
    'last_name' => 'griffin',
    'company' => 'Nantuket Brewing',
    'Addresses' => [
      [
        'addr1' => '31 Spooner Ln',
        'city' => 'Quahog',
        'state' => 'RI'
      ],
      // possible more addresses here
    ],
  ],
  // possible more items here
  // [
  //   'email' => 'x@y.z',
  //   ...
  // ]
];

$asString = json_encode($data);
```

See it [online](https://3v4l.org/vlGhg).

---

In PHP an array can be used as a JavaScript/C/C++/etc array, with numeric indices starting from 0 or it can be used as a JavaScript object, when its keys are strings.

The outer array (`$data`) is a standard array, its keys are numbers starting from `0`. Each of its items is an associative array; their keys are strings (`'email'`, `'firstname'` and so on).

The value of property `Addresses` of each item is an array indexed by numbers. Each of its items (each address) are associative arrays.

PHP encodes the arrays that have numeric consecutive keys starting from `0` as arrays in JSON. All the other PHP arrays (associative arrays, arrays that have numeric keys with gaps, not in order or with negative indices) are encoded as objects in JSON.

--

**The code above produces a JSON equivalent to the value of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` that you put in the question.** By default [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) produces a compact JSON, without unneeded spaces.
It can be told to produce a pretty formatted JSON (by passing `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` as its second argument) but a pretty printed JSON is useful only for debugging. The destination server should not care about the formatting and it only increases the JSON's size.

Comment: TY. JSON_PRETTY_PRINT was helpful. Any thoughts on why json_encode is converting my arrays [] to object {}s?  $insertStr = str_replace(["{","}"], ["[{", "}]"], $insertStr); changes them back and then it works.

Comment: I explained in the answer when it produces objects because it cannot produce arrays. It is also explained in the PHP documentation somewhere (I cannot remember exactly where). The PHP arrays are actually not pure arrays but a combination of arrays, double-linked lists and hashes/maps/dictionaries (PHP calls these data structures "associative arrays"). The associative arrays are objects under disguise (and easier to use that `stdClass`). The pure arrays have consecutive numeric keys starting from zero (and no gaps). Only these can be encoded as arrays in JSON because only they are arrays.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-notes

Comment: Sorry, the "terse" version actually helped it make sense. Thank you for your help and tutelage!